# How to toggle the movement between two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made two boxes with `div` to move them with arrow keys and it works just fine with a single box. But when I added the second box, they both started to move at the same time even though I've given them different IDs. What I want to achieve is that when the user hits Spacebar, the first box to be disabled and the second box activated. I've also searched up for something similiar but I could not find anything. So I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hognmqdu/) here so you can take a closer look.

And this is my JQuery code:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
            switch (e.which) {
                case 37:
                    jQuery("#cube").stop().animate({ left: '-=10' });
                    break;
                case 38:
                    jQuery("#cube").stop().animate({ top: '-=10' });
                    break;
                case 39:
                    jQuery("#cube").stop().animate({ left: '+=10' });
                    break;
                case 40:
                    jQuery("#cube").stop().animate({ top: '+=10' });
                    break;
            }
        });

        var space = false;
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery(document).keydown(function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
                    space = true;
                }
            });
        });
        if (space == true) {
            jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
                switch (e.which) {
                    case 37:
                        jQuery("#cubetwo").stop().animate({ left: '-=10' });
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        jQuery("#cubetwo").stop().animate({ top: '-=10' });
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        jQuery("#cubetwo").stop().animate({ left: '+=10' });
                        break;
                    case 40:
                        jQuery("#cubetwo").stop().animate({ top: '+=10' });
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to include jquery in you jsfiddle. And you can just use one `keydown` event to catch all the behaviors.

When user press space, switch the target that will be moved.

When arrow key is pressed, move the target.

EDITED:

If your expecting behavior is : Only when pressing `space`, the arrow key will affect to `#cubetwo`, otherwise move `#cube`, then you can add `keyup` event to achieve this, just use the commented out part in `/* */` instead.

As add another snippet will be too long for an answer, I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hognmqdu/2/) for you to test the second behavior, choose one that you expect.

```js
var space = false;
var target = space ? jQuery("#cube") : jQuery("#cubetwo");
/*
var target = jQuery("#cube");
*/
jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37:
        target.stop().animate({ left: '-=10' });
      break;
      case 38:
        target.stop().animate({ top: '-=10' });
        break;
      case 39:
        target.stop().animate({ left: '+=10' });
        break;
      case 40:
        target.stop().animate({ top: '+=10' });
        break;
      case 32:
        // Swtich target.
        space = !space;
        target = space ? jQuery("#cube") : jQuery("#cubetwo");
        /*
        target = jQuery("#cubetwo");
        */
      break;
  }
});

/*
jQuery(document).keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.which === 32) {
     target = jQuery("#cube");
   }
});
*/
```

```css
#cube {
            height: 125px;
            width: 125px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: green;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        #cubetwo {
            height: 125px;
            width: 125px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: blue;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0px;
            left: 700px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="cube">
        Press arrow keys to move me
    </div>
    <div id="cubetwo">
        Hit space to activate me
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
/* controlled cube */
var whichCube = jQuery("#cube");

/* arrows*/
jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
            switch (e.which) {
                case 37:
                    whichCube.stop().animate({ left: '-=10' });
                    break;
                case 38:
                    whichCube.stop().animate({ top: '-=10' });
                    break;
                case 39:
                    whichCube.stop().animate({ left: '+=10' });
                    break;
                case 40:
                    whichCube.stop().animate({ top: '+=10' });
                    break;
            }
 });

 /* space */
 jQuery(document).keydown(function (evt) {
            if (evt.keyCode == 32) /*space*/ {

          /*toggle 1->2, or 2->1 */

               if(whichCube == jQuery("#cube"))                      
                            whichCube = jQuery("#cubeTwo");
               else         
                            whichCube = jQuery("#cube");
            }
        });

        }
```

Comment: The problem is solved. @fuyushimoya's solution is more radical. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @AltayMazlum yes fuyu'has given a good answer ! thanks,please leave me a +1 by passing.